# Outlook VBA to save sent meeting requests/replies to a specified folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook, office365

I found the code below [(here)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/59f2068a-0891-4a5c-9bcf-82626ea2295f/outlook-vba-to-save-sent-email-to-a-public-folder?forum=outlookdev) to get outlook VBA to save sent email to a specified folder.

The code works well, however, any time that it runs on a sent meeting request or meeting reply, it errors.

I have been able to identify line 9 as the line where the error occurs:

```
Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
```

My assumption, then, is that the `Item.SaveSentMessageFolder` code is incompatible with meeting-type objects.  However, I am uncertain as to what the equivalent coding would be for meeting-type objects.

Can this code be modified to handle meeting-type objects in the same fashion that message-type objects are handled?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
    Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
  Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
  If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" And _
     IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) Then
      Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
  End If
  Set objFolder = Nothing
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function IsInDefaultStore(objOL As Object) As Boolean
  Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  On Error Resume Next
  Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Select Case objOL.Class
    Case olFolder
      If objOL.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
        IsInDefaultStore = True
      End If
    Case olAppointment, olContact, olDistributionList, _
         olJournal, olMail, olNote, olPost, olTask
      If objOL.Parent.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
        IsInDefaultStore = True
      End If
    Case Else
      MsgBox "This function isn't designed to work " & _
             "with " & TypeName(objOL) & _
             " items and will return False.", _
             , "IsInDefaultStore"
  End Select
  Set objApp = Nothing
  Set objNS = Nothing
  Set objInbox = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/savesentmessagefolder-read-only-when-sending-appointments.2997156/

Comment: Thanks @timwilliams, the conclusion at the link was, "I don't think you can make use of this property for outgoing meeting requests."  I agree with this conclusion.  I am wondering if I can modify the code above to achieve the same effect (without using the SaveSentMessageFolder property).

Comment: I'm not that familiar with handling appointments in Outlook: I guess you could try just moving the item?

Comment: MeetingItem object does have the SaveSentMessageFolder property. What is the exact error?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - now that I've been tinkering with it, I can't quite seem to get the error message to display.  The macro is running without an error message, but the appointment item is still not being moved to the specified folder.  When I enter the following code into the immediate window while creating a meeting request, it returns run-time error '438': "Object doesn't support this property or method". `debug.Print application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.SaveSentMessageFolder`

Comment: That's to be expected - you cannot print an object of type MAPIFolder. Try debug.Print application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.SaveSentMessageFolde‌​r.Name

Comment: Same results with and without ".Name" for an appointment object - run-time error 438.  When I use the same code in the immediate window for a new message, it returns "Sent Items" (with and without ".Name").

Comment: I will guess you don't not know how to use On Error Resume Next so code "works perfectly" except for not doing anything. http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm

Comment: Good strategy of looking for the error handlers, @niton .  However, the error message was originally occurring in the sub after the function had been called and run successfully, whereas the error handler was within the function exclusively.  In my reply to @Dimitry above, I wrote that I couldn't "get the error message to display" again.  This was because I had added an error handler (`On Error Resume Next`) immediately before the problem code (line 9), as a temporary work-around until we could reach the desired solution.  The code above does not reflect this addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one other person has found the property to be ineffective for meeting items.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/meetingitem-savesentmessagefolder-property-outlook

"Setting or getting this property has no noticeable effect. Do not use this property."

Try monitoring the Sent Items folder.

Place this code in the ThisOutlookSession module.

```
Private WithEvents sentMailItems As items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set sentMailItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).items
End Sub

Private Sub sentMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objFolder As Folder

    If TypeOf Item Is MeetingItem Then

        Set objFolder = Session.PickFolder

        If TypeName(objFolder) <> "Nothing" Then
            Item.Move objFolder
        End If

    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It appears that this solution (handling the message after it is sent) rather than the originally desired solution (handling the message preemptively before it is sent) is the most feasible way to reach the end objective (prompt user to select a folder other then 'sent'). Therefore, I will implement this solution. Thank you for your research @niton